# Add marker with Google Maps Javascript API to look exactly as marker that were added in maps.google.com

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to add map to my site using Google Maps Javascript API. I want it to looks exactly like map that was created with maps.google.com:

[image]

But I can not achieve this result, just this:

[image]

So my question is: how to add red dot at the bottom of a marker, and how to make title to be written on the right side of this dot in bold?

This is my code:

```
function initMap() {
    var coordinates = { lat: 40.785845, lng: -74.020496 };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: coordinates,
        scrollwheel: false
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coordinates,
        map: map,
        label: "5409 Madison St"
    });
  }
```

Comment: BTW, if all you need is just to add a map to your site, it's much easier to do with Maps Embeded API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-started) that lets you add a map with improved abilities (like "route" button) using a simple line of code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To customize the label text see the documentation for the [markerLabel](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerLabel) anonymous object.  To control the position of the label, you need to use the [Icon `labelOrigin`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) property.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: coordinates,
  map: map,
  icon: {
    url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png",
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(75, 32),
    size: new google.maps.Size(32,32),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(16,32)
  },
  label: {
    text: "5409 Madison St",
    color: "#C70E20",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
});
```

To add the "red dot" ("measle") at the bottom of the marker, the simplest way is to create another marker at the same location (although you could create an icon for your marker that includes both the measle and the default red "bubble" marker).

```
var measle = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: coordinates,
  map: map,
  icon: {
    url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
    size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(4, 4)
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zh5c2pwj/3/)

[image: red text marker]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var coordinates = {
    lat: 40.785845,
    lng: -74.020496
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: coordinates,
    scrollwheel: false
  });
  var measle = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coordinates,
    map: map,
    icon: {
      url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
      size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(3.8, 3.8)
    }
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coordinates,
    map: map,
    icon: {
      url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png",
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(75, 32),
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
    },
    label: {
      text: "5409 Madison St",
      color: "#C70E20",
      fontWeight: "bold"
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```