# Set Google map location AND get rid of box

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am attempting to solve two problems. I can solve each one individually, but not at the same time.

I want
 1. To have a google map on my site that has a specific location already loaded when the page loads, aka the red arrow thing is there
 2. To get rid of the grey box in the upper left hand corner

Getting the location is easy. You just use an iframe. I did it like this:

```
<div style="border-radius: 250px; width: 500px; overflow: hidden; margin-top: 90px; margin-bottom: 90px;">
    <iframe id="map" width="500" height="500" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:ChIJm04kiUOHj4AR8NnaLQ2OCXw&key=MYAPIKEY" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

But the iframe comes with a little box in the upper lefthand corner. I don't want that and I need it to go away.

So I tried using the Google Maps API. With JavaScript, I am able to remove the box like so:

```
<div id="map_container" >
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>

<script>
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: {lat: -33, lng: 151},
      disableDefaultUI: true
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

This works fine, except I can't seem to have the same red arrow set. This is a site for a business, so I can't just set the lat and lng. I need the red arrow directly over the business. I can't seem to find the answer to both of these questions on Stack Overflow. Help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add marker with Google Maps Javascript API to look exactly as marker that were added in maps.google.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165971/add-marker-with-google-maps-javascript-api-to-look-exactly-as-marker-that-were-a)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Javascript API you'll need to first look up the coordinates of your business' Place ID using the Places API, and then pass that into the map.

Check out the example half way down the page here
https://developers.google.com/places/place-id

However if all you want to do is hide the info box, you can use embed in the 'view' mode:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=[your key]&q=place_id:ChIJm04kiUOHj4AR8NnaLQ2OCXw" />
```

The various embed modes are described in the docs
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

Comment: All I want to do is hide the box. I tried what you have here and got 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()' in the console.  

<div id="map_container">
 <iframe id="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=[MYAPIKEY]&q=place_id:ChIJm04kiUOHj4AR8NnaLQ2OCXw" /></iframe>

</div>

Comment: Using this, I can get my location. How would I edit this exact code to get rid of the box? Thank you!
<iframe id="map" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:ChIJm04kiUOHj4AR8NnaLQ2OCXw&key=[APIKEY]" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can not keep the red arrow AND get rid of the grey box at the same time. BUT you can do it with CSS. In my case, I want my map to be a circle. So I put the map in a circle container with the overflow:hidden set on the container. Then I made the width and height of the iframe 170%, which pushes the box out of view. Then it's just a matter of using relative positioning to push the arrow back to the center of the map. Here's how I did it.

```
<div id="map_container">
    <iframe id="map" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:ChIJm04kiUOHj4AR8NnaLQ2OCXw&key=[MYAPIKEY]" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div>


#map {
width: 170%;
height: 170%;
position:relative;
top: -120px;
left: -120px;
}
#map_container {
-webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
width: 350px;
height: 350px;
overflow: hidden; 
margin-top: 90px; 
margin-bottom: 90px;
border-radius: 250px;
}
```

The webkit bit is to prevent the full sized map from flickering around the edges. You obviously still need to plug in a valid API key to get this to work.