# How to use new Google Maps official map marker (JavaScript API) Dec-17

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm wondering how can I use the new official Google Maps map marker, in my web-application with Google Maps API v3 (JavaScript).

This is the picture. I like it.

[image]

[image]

By the way, is there a way to change its color?

Thanks and happy x-mas :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add marker with Google Maps Javascript API to look exactly as marker that were added in maps.google.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165971/add-marker-with-google-maps-javascript-api-to-look-exactly-as-marker-that-were-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add the google maps' marker. You can only use the [default marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=fr) or [custom your marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers?hl=fr#presentation).

This is an example of default marker:

```js
      function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

And this is an example of custom marker:

```js
var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91722, 151.23064),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        var icons = {
          parking: {
            icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
          },
          library: {
            icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
          },
          info: {
            icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
          }
        };

        var features = [
          {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91721, 151.22630),
            type: 'info'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91539, 151.22820),
            type: 'info'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91747, 151.22912),
            type: 'info'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91910, 151.22907),
            type: 'info'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91725, 151.23011),
            type: 'info'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91872, 151.23089),
            type: 'info'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91784, 151.23094),
            type: 'info'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91682, 151.23149),
            type: 'info'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91790, 151.23463),
            type: 'info'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91666, 151.23468),
            type: 'info'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.916988, 151.233640),
            type: 'info'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91662347903106, 151.22879464019775),
            type: 'parking'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.916365282092855, 151.22937399734496),
            type: 'parking'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91665018901448, 151.2282474695587),
            type: 'parking'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.919543720969806, 151.23112279762267),
            type: 'parking'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91608037421864, 151.23288232673644),
            type: 'parking'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91851096391805, 151.2344058214569),
            type: 'parking'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91818154739766, 151.2346203981781),
            type: 'parking'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91727341958453, 151.23348314155578),
            type: 'library'
          }
        ];

        // Create markers.
        features.forEach(function(feature) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: map
          });
        });
      }
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

*Tell me if you have some questions.*

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Happy x-mas!