# How can i add marker on google map

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I want it to mark the desired place on Google map, how can I do that?

```
<google-map id="map-container" width="100%" height="100%" class="maps"></google-map>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add marker with Google Maps Javascript API to look exactly as marker that were added in maps.google.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165971/add-marker-with-google-maps-javascript-api-to-look-exactly-as-marker-that-were-a)

Answer (score 0):

You can add it like this in angular:

```
<google-map>
  <map-marker
    *ngFor="let marker of markers"
    [position]="marker.position"
    [label]="marker.label"
    [title]="marker.title"
    [options]="marker.options"
  >
  </map-marker>
</google-map>

// Add to list like this way
this.markers.push({
  position: {
    lat: latitudeValue,
    lng: longitudeValue,
  },
  label: {
    color: 'red',
    text: 'Marker label ' + (this.markers.length + 1),
  },
  title: 'Marker title ' + (this.markers.length + 1),
  options: { animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE },
});
```

Comment: How should the list of markers be?

Comment: @VolkanUstekidag please check updated answer.